# How to serialize and restore vuex store state?

Tags: javascript, serialization, vue.js, persistence, vuex

I´m using vuex for a very simple single purpose application. I would like to include a functionality that enables users to get a string(/url) that they can save to later recreate the store state.

For this, I thought it would be the easiest way to just dump the store state and later reinitialize the app with this dump.

Any idea how to achieve this?

I looked into the existing vuex persistence libraries but they seem to be overkill for what I´m aiming for. Simplicity beats sophistication in this scenario.

vuex persistance libraries I looked at
https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate
https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer in the Vue Discord chat:

"just JSON.stringify it"

Example: https://github.com/devCrossNet/chaptr/blob/master/src/app/home/Home/Home.vue#L118

Works like a charm.